# Interleaved usleep() functions being executed together. Is this compiler optimization?

Tags: c, linux

I have a code that does something similar to the following repeatedly over a loop:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','!'};
    for(int x=0; x<6 ; x++){
        printf("%c",arr[x]);
        usleep(1000000);
        printf("%c",arr[x]);
        usleep(1000000);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I see that `printf()` executes one after the other WITHOUT any delay (due to `usleep`), and then the program sleeps for the total `usleep` time at the end before the next iteration. Seems like all the `usleep()` calls happen together in the end.

I tried `-O0` flag in gcc, because I suspected its the effect of compiler optimization. But I guess `-O0` flag does not disable whatever optimization category this case falls under (if my guess is correct about the compiler being the reason for this behavior).

I am trying to understand the reason for this behavior and how to achieve the desired behavior from my program.

Note: I know it might be possible to replace `usleep()` with some compute-heavy function call that take an equivalent amount of time, but that is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Don't describe the code, show the code. See [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And as mentioned, please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: A C compiler wouldn't combine calls to `usleep()`. Something else must be the cause.

Comment: Here you go, an example @user3386109 

char arr[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','!'};
for(int x=0; x<6 ; x++){
    printf("%c",arr[x]);
    usleep(1000000);
}

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf`.

Comment: That's just output buffering. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201083/sleep-delays-output-until-end.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat TY! Looked into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901901/what-does-fflushstdin-do-in-c-programing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off buffering of stdout in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7876660/608639), [sleep() delays output until end](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4201083/608639), etc

Answer (score 0):

You are using `usleep()` wrong. Use `sleep(1)` instead.

From `man usleep`:

> EINVAL usec is greater than or equal to 1000000.  (On systems where that is considered an error.)

Once you fix that you should do `fflush()` after `printf()` to avoid another surprise with output buffering.

Comment: "*On systems where that is considered an error.*" Which systems are those?

Comment: @melpomome: I encountered it on Linux a long time ago and switched to select with no handles.